# Having issues exiting my while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been testing my code for the past few hours and I am stumped. This program takes a text file of names, turns the names into a list, prints the names, sorts the names, prints the sorted names, then allows you to search through the list. Everything seems to be working fine, but the one issue I have is exiting the while loop. If y or Y is selected you can search again, but that also happens if anything else is selected. I added a print statement outside the loop so if anything other than y is selected then the program should end with that last printed string, but it doesn't seem to be working. Does anyone have any ideas about why it isn't working and what I could change to get it to work?

Thank you for your time.

```
#define the main function
def main():

    #create a variable to control the loop
    keep_going = 'y'

    #setup loop to search for name
    while keep_going == 'y' or keep_going == 'Y':    

        #call input name function
        names = input_name()

        #call print name function
        print_name(names)

        #sort the printed list
        names.sort()

        #call the print name function
        print_name(names)

        #call the output name function
        output_name(names)

        #call the search name function
        search_name(names)

        #add user input for another search
        search_again = input('Would you like to make another search?(y for yes): ')   

    #print if anything other than y or Y is selected
    print()
    print('Goodbye!')

#define the input function   
def input_name():

    #open the names.txt file
    infile = open('names.txt', 'r')

    #read contents into a list
    names = infile.readlines()

    #close the file
    infile.close()

    #strip the \n from each element
    index = 0
    while index < len(names):
        names[index] = names[index].rstrip('\n')
        index += 1

    #return the list back to main function    
    return names

#define the print name function
def print_name(names):

    #print the contents of the list
    for name in names:
        print(name)

#define the output name function
def output_name(names):

    #open file for writing
    outfile = open('sorted_names.txt', 'w')

    #write the list to the file
    for item in names:
        outfile.write(item + '\n')

    #close the file
    outfile.close()

    #return to main function
    return

#define the search name function
def search_name(names):

    #add a user input to search the file
    search = input('Enter a name: ')

    #determine whether the name is in the list
    if search in names:

        #get the names index
        name_index = names.index(search)

        #print the name was found and give the items index
        print(search, "was found in list. This item's index is", name_index)         

    else:

        #print the item was not found
        print(search, 'was not found in the list.')    

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#create a variable to control the loop
keep_going = 'y'

#setup loop to search for name
while keep_going == 'y' or keep_going == 'Y':

    #add user input for another search
    search_again = input('Would you like to make another search?(y for yes): ')
```

You never set `keep_going` to something else. Instead, you ask the user to enter `y` to continue but store it in `search_again` (which is then thrown away). You will want to change that to store the value in `keep_going`.

Answer (score 0):

You are testing keep_going, but setting search_again

Answer (score 0):

Replace line 29 which states:

```
search_again = input('Would you like to make another search?(y for yes): ')
```

with the following:

```
keep_going = input('Would you like to make another search?(y for yes): ')
```

Because when you enter `y` or `Y` then you are defining the variable `search_again` to that letter not the variable `keep_going` which is needed to change for the loop to stop.